# How do I set permissions for a specific (mounted) location?

Tags: mount, permissions, filesystem

My system has two (major) partitions: my Ubuntu install (mounted at `/`, obviously), and my Windows install (mounted at `/win32`).

Furthermore, I've symlinked some folders from my Windows partition over to by Ubuntu partition (namely `~/Documents`, `~/Music`, `~/Videos`, and the like). This way, I have my system set up so that some folders stay in sync with each other in a reliable manner.

However, I occasionally run into the problem where I can't alter permissions at all, because the files are owned by `root` and not me.

Ideally, I'd like to set up (somehow) my system in such a way that `/win32/Users/Owner` (and nothing else) has both my user and group set as the owner instead of root. I'd also like to keep `root` as the owner of everything else, such as to avoid accidental mistakes on my part.

Is this even possible? How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mount `/win32` as CIFS from an `fstab` entry, then you can set the `uid` and `gid` (as well as other options related to user mapping and permissions - see `man mount.cifs`) in the mount options in `/etc/fstab`.

I have no Windows partitions to verify this, but am quite sure that you could mount them more than once.  So you would mount the root of the Windows partition as read-only on `/win32`, and the user home directory read-write somewhere else.
I'm not sure if that could be at `/win32/Users/Owner`, i.e. overlaying the mounted `/win32` tree.  It can for some filesystems, not for all.

If CIFS doesn't allow such a mount, then maybe a bind mount (see `man mount`) can do the trick.  Otherwise of course you could mount it outside the `/win32` tree, e.g. at `~user/win32` or something.